# What to name a magic (technicaly mana type) type that runs on emotion?

Tags: magic, names

I have three types of magic in my world, this unnamed type, spiritual and arcane. All magic types can be used exclusively to create magic.

For this emotional magic it would generate from **any** heightened emotions but can positively or negatively affect the other types of magic. This energy can also be generated in others that are the driving cause of a high emotional state in another although negative emotions generate more.

Because of these things this magic type is notoriously used and relied upon by demons and is the driving influence in them being 'evil' although not all demons are evil.

For additional (but undetailed) information, arcane uses mana which is passively generated from souls and there's spiritual which is generated with worship and/or a combination of fear and respect.

[Edit 2: The magic types' particular magic energy will be refereed to as spiritual energy and arcane energy or similar.]

With this in mind I don't want to call this magic ***'demonic'*** magic as it isn't even remotely exclusive to them (and would be attributed to magic of demonic design). Neither do I want to call this ***'chaos'*** magic as I don't really feel it fits.

I *especially* **do not** wish to unify my magic types as I prefer them to be considered three separate systems that merely interact with each other to produce more complex results.

**Edit:** I need to add That I can't change it to dark or black, as I would also change spiritual to light (though they don't seem to theme that well with how they work) , because of my elements. These are Earth, Lightning, Air, Water, Fire, Frost, Light and Dark.

Apologies if this is in the wrong place.

Comment: What to name your specific magic system has nothing to do with World Building AFAICT. Why can't you just call it "emotional magic"?

Comment: call it dark magic?

Comment: @Aify Sorry as far as I could tell this was the place I would ask this but I could be wrong, I don't want to call tit emotional magic because it doesn't seem to fit some kind of theme with the others.

Comment: I vote for Willbending

Comment: Willbending sounds amazing, but it could be a little misleading, it sounds more like controlling wills than drawing from them. OP might clarify to explain what this magic does, not just how its used

Comment: Asking what to name something is extremely opinion based.

Comment: @sphennings Sorry, The only thing i can say in my defence is I desperately need resources as I have been looking for weeks for something to give me this idea. I should have looked for a different site as this isn't its purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### "Pathos" or "pathic" magic

The Greek word *πάθος páthos* means "suffering", but in English derivatives it tends to mean "emotion" in general. It's the root of sympathy, empathy, telepathy, and so on.

In particular, Aristotle (in his *Rhetotic*) used it as the name of one of the three methods of persuasion: *pathos* included appeals to emotion and ad hominem attacks, ways of pulling at your audience's emotions to make them feel in their heart that you're right. Metaphors and anecdotes were important parts of *pathos* persuasion.

The usual adjective form would be **pathetic** from *παθητικός pathēticós*, but that has different connotations in English. (Compare the meaning in other languages, though, e.g. Beethoven's famous *Sonata Pathétique*.) So I would recommend **pathic** (by analogy with empathic, telepathic) or simply **pathos**.

Comment: I was going to answer Empathy but I see your answer mostly covers that already. I'd go with Empathy over Pathos though as it's more immediately familiar and obvious to most people while still being a little mysterious / uncommon.

Comment: @adaliabooks The main issue with using empathy, and drives me crazy, is that it has highly positive connotations and I don't want to emphasise either positive or negative emotions. As usual I could just be wrong and I may need to ask about that some where else.

Answer (score 2):

**Passionate magic.**

From the oxford English dictionary:   Esp. of a person: susceptible to or readily swayed by passions or emotions; easily moved to strong feeling; of changeable mood, volatile.

Of a person: affected with passion or strong feeling; dominated by intense emotion; ardently enthusiastic. Also: zealously devoted, attached, or loyal.

A thing influenced by emotion describes this magic.  Of note: passion and passionate in common parlance connotes romance and love.  But one can passionately hate as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing seems closest to what D&D (and many other created worlds) refer to as sorcery which is a force that comes from within and is created by willpower (or in this case emotion). I would recommend looking at something like that.

Sorcery might not be the correct name for your emotional magic however, as it sounds more like bewitchment or enchanting (the spells on people kind) because it feeds off emotions. You could even call it something as cliche as wizardry because that wouldn't necessarily box you into a corner and as you've already decided to create your own magic system wizardry (or similar) could be defined to mean anything you want.

One final alternative would be to make up a word or series of words to represent this form of magic.

Best of luck

Comment: This is extremely helpful assuming no one has an idea that fits closer and that it shows me more that i need to clarify. The only reason I don't botch together a word is because I wanted a word that conveyed what it was and did in English without being literal aka emotional.